# Change in RDKit's encoding of InChi?

Tags: computational-chemistry, rdkit

Using RDKit (2020.09.5) I would like to assign InChi to molecules expressed as SMILES and fail to replicate this [GitHub gist](https://gist.github.com/vfscalfani/f10c4718e8d2e48586c48674a654aa20) for initial training written about 2 years ago (RDKit 2019.03.2). I would like to know if the required instruction changed, or if I miss importing/adjusting a relevant function/parameter then causing the errors.

To quote the relevant code there:

```py
# Load RDKit modules
from rdkit import Chem
from rdkit.Chem.Draw import IPythonConsole
from rdkit.Chem import Draw

# Construct a molecular object from a SMILES string
m1 = Chem.MolFromSmiles('COC(=O)C1CN1C(=O)OCC2=CC=CC=C2')

# Calculate InChI
Chem.MolToInchi(m1)

# Calculate InChIKey
Chem.MolToInchiKey(m1)
```

However, neither the anticipated InChi (`'InChI=1S/C12H13NO4/c1-16-11(14)10-7-13(10)12(15)17-8-9-5-3-2-4-6-9/h2-6,10H,7-8H2,1H3'`) nor the hash, i.e. InChiKey `'GTZJUBQWCWZING-UHFFFAOYSA-N'` are accessible for me.

Instead, the Jupyter notebook mentions the following errors:

```bash
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-9-71f9b591b71d> in <module>
      8 
      9 # Calculate InChI
---> 10 Chem.MolToInchi(m1)
     11 
     12 # Calculate InChIKey

AttributeError: module 'rdkit.Chem' has no attribute 'MolToInchi'
```

Following the recommendation in RDKit's manual here, I thought the substitution of `Chem.MolToInchi(m1)` by `Chem.inchi.MolToInchi(m1)` would remove the road block.  Contrary to anticipation, however, this doesn't work either:

```bash
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-10-cddee16a293d> in <module>
      9 # Calculate InChI
     10 # Chem.MolToInchi(m1)
---> 11 Chem.inchi.MolToInchi(m1)
     12 
     13 # Calculate InChIKey

AttributeError: module 'rdkit.Chem.inchi' has no attribute 'MolToInchi'
```

Comment: +10 nice first question Buttonwood! Hopefully after you wrote all those excellent answers here, someone will be able to return the favor and answer yours!

Comment: Its presumably an issue of your Jupyter environment. From a fresh install of rdkit `2021.03`, I was able to execute the original code from the terminal. You may try to check the version being used within Jupyter `import rdkit; print(rdkit.__version__)`

Comment: @Tyberius As stated above, `202009.5-1` (or `2020.09.5` by `import rdkit; help(rdkit); G`) is the currently latest available version packaged for [Debian 12/bookworm (testing)](https://tracker.debian.org/pkg/rdkit).  Yet I read your comment as invite to install `rdkit` in `miniconda`.  Weekend, here I am ...

Comment: Downgrading to `2020.09.5` and running in Jupyter still worked for me, though I'm using an Ubuntu20.04 machine. For checking the version, I was more curious if the intended version wasn't matching the one being used by Jupyter for some reason.

Answer (score 3):

Following `@Tyberius` suggest, I departed from using Jupyter notebook in favor of the CLI.  In contrast of the GitHub gist,* the following script is to report InChi and InChiKey about pyridine:

```py
#!/bin/usr/env python3

import rdkit
from rdkit import Chem

molecule = Chem.MolFromSmiles('n1ccccc1')

inchi = str(Chem.MolToInchi(molecule))
inchikey = str(Chem.MolToInchiKey(molecule))

print(inchi)
print(inchikey)
```

to yield the strings

```
InChI=1S/C5H5N/c1-2-4-6-5-3-1/h1-5H
JUJWROOIHBZHMG-UHFFFAOYSA-N
```

These match the output provided e.g., by the [ChemDraw JS Sample Page](https://chemdrawdirect.perkinelmer.cloud/js/sample/index.html#).

---

Notes taken *en route* to this result:

- Following the instructions by [RDKit](https://www.rdkit.org/docs/Install.html), a separate second Python interpreter was set up based on [Miniconda](https://docs.conda.io/en/latest/miniconda.html).  While substantially smaller than a full Anaconda ecosystem, past the creation of a virtual environment by

  ```
  conda create -c conda-forge -n my-rdkit-env rdkit
  ```

  the installation requires about $\pu{1.5 GB}$ free space to include larger dependencies like `matplotlib`, or `pandas`.
- As of writing, this offers Python 3.9.7 and rdkit 2021.03.5 when working from the terminal.  The version of the later may be checked by either `print(rdkit.__version__)`, or `import rdkit; help(rdkit); G`.  For a reason beyond the scope of this question, Jupyter still was loading the elder version of rdkit provided by the hosting OS, 2020.09.5.
- *) RDKit 2019.03.2 the GitHub gist mentioned seems to be fine with the aziridine defined by the SMILES string `COC(=O)C1CN1C(=O)OCC2=CC=CC=C2`. The present version of RDKit however recognizes the ambiguity present and prepends a note in the pattern of:

  ```
  [hh:mm:ss] WARNING: Omitted undefined stereo
  InChI=1S/C12H13NO4/c1-16-11(14)10-7-13(10)12(15)17-8-9-5-3-2-4-6-9/h2-6,10H,7-8H2,1H3
  GTZJUBQWCWZING-UHFFFAOYSA-N
  ```

  In line with this, the Inchi -> structure conversion provided by the [PubChem Sketcher](https://pubchem.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/edit3/index.html) draws a structure formula lacking wedges as if there were no (*R*)/(*S*) configuration.

Comment: +1 Great work figuring this out on your own and then sharing it with this whole community in case future users may find it useful!